# complex join in sql combining 6 tables

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I am trying to join 6 tables using this code

```
select publications.ISSUE_NUMBER,publications.pages,publications.ihe_issue_id , 
       publications.PUBLISHER_NAME , people.first_name, 
       people.last_name,countries.country, people.email, content.name_display
FROM publications
join content
content.content_id = publications.content_id
join people
people.content_id = content.content_id
JOIN pubauthor_people ON 
people.people_id = pubauthor_people.people_id 
JOIN countries ON 
countries.country_id = people.mail_country_id 
JOIN content ON
content.content_id = people.content_id
```

I am getting an error

> ORA-00905: missing keyword.

I don't think I am missing a keyword.

Comment: ON conditions for the first two?

Comment: select ISSUE_NUMBER,pages,ihe_issue_id , 
PUBLISHER_NAME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you appear to be missing the `ON` in your first two joins.

```
FROM publications
     JOIN content ON <== missing ON
       content.content_id = publications.content_id
     JOIN people ON <== missing ON
       people.content_id = content.content_id
```

Comment: select ISSUE_NUMBER,pages,ihe_issue_id , 
PUBLISHER_NAME this works but when i join it with the rest it wont work

Comment: @user3841039 - If "won't work" means that you are getting an ORA-00905 error, then, as has been pointed out, you're missing a couple of `ON` keywords so a missing keyword error seems eminently reasonable.  If "won't work" means something else, you're going to have to be more specific in telling us what isn't working.

Comment: no it says no data found and i fixed the ON problem

Comment: @user3841039 - "no data found" means that the query ran successfully but returned no rows.  If you believe that rows should have been returned, you would need to explain to us why you believe that.  That would involve things like posting the DDL for your tables, the DML to populate a few rows of sample data, the query you're running, and the expected results. If you want to investigate the problem yourself, build up the query one table at a time and figure out which join(s) are discarding rows that you expect to be returned.

Comment: SELECT 
first_name, last_name, countries.country, email,content.name_display
FROM
people 
JOIN pubauthor_people ON 
people.people_id = pubauthor_people.people_id 
JOIN countries ON 
countries.country_id = people.mail_country_id 
JOIN content ON
content.content_id = people.content_id

SELECT ISSUE_NUMBER,pages,ihe_issue_id , 
       PUBLISHER_NAME 
FROM publications these joins work sepertly but together they dont

Comment: @user3841039 - Like I said, if you want assistance debugging a data problem, you'd need to post a lot more information.  Please don't post that in comments.  It sounds like your initial question has been answered.  If that is the case, you'd want to create a new question to ask your new question.  In that question, post a reproducible test case that shows the problem.  Show code and show results.  Saying things like "joins work separately but together they don't", unfortunately, doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 1):

For the first two `JOIN` you are missing `ON` keyword as pointed below

```
FROM publications
join content
content.content_id = publications.content_id <-- Here
join people
people.content_id = content.content_id <-- Here
```

Sidenote: your last `join` with `content` table is unnecessary since you are already doing that while joining with `people` table.

```
JOIN content ON
content.content_id = people.content_id
```

Again one step further, the `JOIN` with `pubauthor_people` table is unnecessary here since I don't see you are fetching any column from that table neither there is dependency relationship with other table.

You final query should look like below

```
select publications.ISSUE_NUMBER,
publications.pages,
publications.ihe_issue_id , 
publications.PUBLISHER_NAME , 
people.first_name, 
people.last_name,
countries.country, 
people.email, 
content.name_display
FROM publications
join content
on content.content_id = publications.content_id
join people
on people.content_id = content.content_id 
JOIN countries ON 
countries.country_id = people.mail_country_id;
```